# Empty cart when confirming order in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.3

I have a problem with my opencart checkout. When you place an order and is about to confirm, you get **Your cart is empty** message.
I saw a suggestion in a [forum](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=19293#p94774), suggesting to change this line:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])));
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
```

to

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
```

but I realized that the change is already in place and the problem still persists.

Comment: Are you using any SEO extension?

Comment: @Konstantinos Botonakis No. I installed a particular extension which was giving me trouble so I uninstall it and remove it's files. Then after I start facing this issue. But I don't get any error from the error log files.